# Trouble passing an object through a function into a new variable

Tags: javascript, object

I'm very new to javascript and have not had any formal education on it. I've looked at multiple sources and I can't seem to find a solution to my issue.

I am trying to create a button with a value equal to an object that is nested inside other objects. I will have a lot of other buttons on my site with the same function but should refer to different data sets.

When the button is clicked I would like the function to grab the value of the button (which should be an object) and declare a new variable equal to the object that has been passed.

I can print the data I want just fine to the log, but when I try to print the value of the variable that should now how the same data I keep getting `[object Object]`

(From there I will be populating a graph that will change every time a new button is clicked.)

*example of my object*

```js
var Wall = {
  "Option1": {},
  "Option2": {},
  "Option3": {
    "Option1_3": {
      "Option1_1_3": {
        "Total Something": "100",
        "Total Something Else": "20",
        "Another Total": "40",
        "More totals": "20",
        "Total": "20",
      },
      "Option2_1_3": {},
      "Option3_1_3": {}
    },
    "Option2_3": {},
  },
  "Option4": {},
  "Option5": {}
};
```

*creating the button and when clicked function*

```
document.getElementById('Option1_3').innerHTML = (`<button class="button"  value="${Wall.Option3.Option1_3}" onclick= "PopulateGraph(this.value)">Wall Time</button>`);

console.log(Wall.Option3.Option1_3);

function PopulateGraph(val){
    console.log(val);
}
```

*Output*
[image: Output in log]

Comment: Attributes in the markup can only store strings (and that's what you're doing in the `.innerHTML = ...` line). An object will, when converted into a string (e.g. through an implicit call of `.toString()`), end as `[object Object]`

Comment: How about using keys instead of the actual object itself?

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas already mentioned, the content of any `value` attribute can only be a string. So one way of doing what you wanted would be to convert the objects into JSON-strings and convert them beack at the time of the button click:

```js
 var Wall ={
  "Option1":{},
  "Option2":{},
  "Option3":{
    "Option1_3":{
      "Option1_1_3":{
         "Total Something":"100",
         "Total Something Else":"20",
         "Another Total":"40",
         "More totals":"20",
         "Total":"20",
       },
       "Option2_1_3":{},
       "Option3_1_3":{}
    },
    "Option2_3":{},
  },
  "Option4":{},
  "Option5":{}};
document.getElementById('Option1_3').innerHTML = (`<button class="button"  value='${JSON.stringify(Wall.Option3.Option1_3)}' onclick= "PopulateGraph(this.value)">Wall Time</button>`);

// console.log(Wall.Option3.Option1_3);

function PopulateGraph(val){
    console.log(JSON.parse(val));
}
```

```html
<div id="Option1_3"></div>
```

Alternatively you could *not assign* the actual object to the button but only *the key* to finding the object (as a string: `"Wall.Option3.Option1_3"`). The button click handler will then find the object on the basis of the passed key:

```js
var Wall ={
  "Option1":{},
  "Option2":{},
  "Option3":{
    "Option1_3":{
      "Option1_1_3":{
         "Total Something":"100",
         "Total Something Else":"20",
         "Another Total":"40",
         "More totals":"20",
         "Total":"20",
       },
       "Option2_1_3":{},
       "Option3_1_3":{}
    },
    "Option2_3":{},
  },
  "Option4":{},
  "Option5":{}};
document.getElementById('Option1_3').innerHTML = (`<button class="button"
  value="Wall.Option3.Option1_3" onclick= "PopulateGraph(this.value)">Wall Time</button>`);

function PopulateGraph(addr){
     console.log(addr.split('.').reduce((a,c)=>a[c],window));
}
```

```html
<div id="Option1_3"></div>
```

The expression `addr.split('.').reduce((a,c)=>a[c],window)` deserves some further explanation: The "address string" `addr`is first split into its components: `['Wall','Option3','Option1_3']` and then the `reduce()` method is applied. The reduce callback function takes each value in turn and returns an underlying object of the passed `a` object. Initially `a` is set to the `window` object, where the `Wall` variable can be found as a property. The found sub-object is returned and will be used as `a` in the next `reduce`-iteration.

Comment: JSON strings use te `"` to delimit strings. So, you must use single quotes `'` for enclosing your HTML attributes, like in `value='JSON.stringify(...)'`.

Comment: You are the best! I have been trying to figure this out for days. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, I have another question to build off of this. I am now trying to make it so the buttons are created using javascript. The issue I am having is when I set the value of the button to '${JSON.stringify('Wall.'+option[i]+'.option'+j+'_'+k)}'  it sends a string instead of the object. how can I make it so it'll send the object name? I tried using eval() but it didn't work

Comment: I suspect there are more elegant ways of creating your buttons, but in any case: you should prepare a separate question for this (with a minimum complete and verifiable example).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you use `${Wall.Option3.Option1_3}` it is gonna have the  same effect as `Wall.Option3.Option1_3.toString()` which is `[object Object]` (this is true for any objects as well as Arrays)

Your choices here are:

Either use `{JSON.stringify(Wall.Option3.Option1_3)`
Or if you don't wanna output plain JSON you can use `Object.keys()` or some other methods to break down the object before parsing it.